# LinkedList toString method; converting to a single string?

Tags: java, string, linked-list, tostring

I'm trying to convert the values of a linked list's nodes into a single string. For example:

```
"c" -> "a" -> "t"
```

So when I use the built in `toString` method, I get this as an output.

```
"[c, a, t]"
```

Where the entire thing is a string. Is there any method that allows me to merge this into a single string, like so?

```
"cat"
```

Comment: Override the `toString` method and use `replaceAll("\\W+", "")` to remove all non [a-zA-Z0-9_] characters.

Comment: [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, so I run `super()` in my override method, and then I add the `replaceall` to my override method?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8, you can use `joining()` collector:

```
LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
strings.add("c");
strings.add("a");
strings.add("t");

System.out.println(strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

output: `"cat"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        LinkedList<String> list=new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("c");
        list.add("a");
        list.add("t");
        System.out.println(list.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\, ", ""));
```